# Separator at every point of the chart

Tags: wpf, livecharts

Can I create a vertical separator at each point entered on the X axis?

I found only an option

```
Separator sep = new Separator();
sep.Step = 2;
```

Here you can only set a fixed spacing

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the `StrokeThickness` of your `Separator`.

```
sep.StrokeThickness = 1;
```

Or in XAML:

```
<lvc:Axis.Separator>
    <lvc:Separator StrokeThickness="1" />
</lvc:Axis.Separator>
```